# How do I get the XML data that went down the wire from a WCF Service generated from `Add Service Reference`

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, serialization, service

Assume I have code like this:

```
var svc = new Namespace.SvcClient();
var request = new Namespace.SvcRequest();
request.SomeProperty = "Value1";
request.SomeProperty = 4.0d;
var response = svc.Request(request);
SetText(response.Result.ToString());
svc.Close();
```

What I want to have is the **actual** XML that got sent out as the result of `svc.Request(request);` and the **actual** XML response from the server, but I want these from WITHIN my application code. I don't want to log it to a file or anything like that. I want to display the xml to the user.

Comment: As an aside you should not be using the 'using' statement here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I had no idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Configuring Message Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx). You can turn on message tracing and get the exact XML.

Comment: How do I get this into a textbox cleanly? Do I have to do Trace -> File -> System.IO.File.Read -> MyTextbox.Text, that doesn't seem very clean, but maybe there is no better way?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the fact that you want to display it to the user. What if the format isn't XML? Remember that WCF can do a lot more than just SOAP.

Comment: I realize that, in my case it will be SOAP, but I'm interested in getting the RAW message data (whatever it is) and display it to the user of the application.